# Dequeue method java, creating a music shuffle playlist

Tags: java, list, random, collections, queue

I'm having some problems with the method *dequeue*. I need to modify my method to use it in the rest of the code. The method *dequeue* that I already have, only dequeue the elements in order, but I need it to dequeue the elements randomly.

Here are the instructions to modify the method dequeue:

1. Dequeue an element randomly using the variable "last". The variable "last" needs to generate the random positions, this variable is my top too.
2. Move all the elements to the left and assign "null" to my empty positions.
3. If "last" is less than 0, throws IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Here it's my code:

```
public class RandomQueue < T > implements QueueOperations < T > {
    private T[] elements;
    private int last;

    public RandomQueue() {
        last = -1;
        elements = (T[]) new Object[10];
    }

    public RandomQueue(int size) {
        elements = (T[]) new Object[size];
        last = -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
            s += "pos: " + j + "objeto" + elements[j] + "||";
        }

        return s;
    }

    public T last() {
        return elements[last];
    }

    public T first() {
        return elements[0];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return last == -1;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return last == elements.length - 1;
    }

    public void enqueue(T objeto) {
        elements[++last] = objeto;
    }

    public T dequeue() {
        T deq = elements[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
            elements[i] = elements[i + 1];
        }

        last--;
        return deq;
    }
}
```

Another class:

```
 public interface QueueOperations < T > {

    public boolean isEmpty();

    public boolean isFull();

    public T first();

    public T last();

    public T dequeue();

    public void enqueue(T e);
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'd change `dequeue` to do that. It's not what it's expected to do. Couldn't you just implement a random iterator?

Comment: No :( I think there are better solutions to the problem, but professor's instructions.

Comment: Is using an array required to store the elements? Otherwise using an ArrayList or another List would make removal of elements simpler.